# Dependency is not satisfiable: openjdk-14-jre-headless

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to install frostwire 6.9.4 but I get this message.

```
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: openjdk-14-jre-headless
```

I am using frostwire-6.9.4.amd64.deb with UbuntuMate 18.04

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? From where are you installing frostwire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FrostWire versions starting from 6.8.5 (thus including 6.9.4) may be installed normally only on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS.

For Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS you have to use older version which depends on older Java. Use commands below to install:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://prime.frostwire.com/frostwire/6.8.4/frostwire-6.8.4.amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./frostwire-6.8.4.amd64.deb openjdk-11-jre
```

and enjoy.